# Url Dinamica con PHP

Tags: php

tengo el archivo index.php donde se procesaran todas las peticiones, en esta hay un archivo **.htcaccess** el cual tiene estas reglas para hacer este proceso de virtualizar la URL.

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Tengo en mi index.php lo siguiente:

```
    $uri = str_replace($route,"",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    $uri = explode("/",$uri);
    $uri=array_filter($uri,function ($el){
        return $el!="";
    });
```

Esto se supone que debe de separar todos los parametros que esten en la URL virtual, por ejemplo:

`www.example.com/posts/carlos-110/a02kdn` a `[ [0] => "posts", [1] => "carlos-110", [2]=> "a02kdn" ]`

El problema esta en que la URL o el programa se encuentra en una carpeta dentro de mi **htdocs** de mis XAMPP, es decir la URL esta de la siguiente manera `localhost:80/carpeta-proyecto/posts/carlos-110/a02kdn` .

Mi duda es, como puedo saber que **carpeta-proyecto** pertenece a una carpeta, para separarlo de la URL ya que el array que me da con esto me da como primera posición el nombre de la carpeta cuando eso no me sirve.

Salu2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contestando tu pregunta: el codigo es el siguiente

```html
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^.*$ carpeta-proyecto/posts/index.php
```

**Como Concejo:**

Esto en producción no te ocurrirá.  y las reglas que configures en local no funcionan en producción.

Lo ideal es configurar un `vhost` e igualar tu entorno de `desarrollo` lo más parecido posible al de `producción`.

Si utilizas XAMMP

ve a `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra` abre el archivo `httpd-vhosts.conf` agrega el siguiente codigo al final.

```html
<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "C:\miproyecto\httpdocs"
  ServerName miproyecto.loc
  <Directory "C:\miproyecto\httpdocs">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Reinicia XAMMP

Ahora configurar el `host` en windows

ve a  `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` abre el fichero `host` con `notepad`  en modo administrador agrega la siguiente linea

```
127.0.0.1 miproyecto.loc
```

Accede al nevagador  con la url  `miproyecto.loc`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu consejo